# Replace link with empty string based on a wildcard

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

So I have the following method that I'm calling `$text = $this->get('text')` that returns the following items:

> Uploading a photo to test the Twitter API endpoint.
> pic.twitter.com/i4bV2UWkBM

Is there a way that I can take that return and find all `pic.twitter.com` instances and replace it with an empty string or remove the URL?

I tried to use:

```
$text = str_replace(
    'pic.twitter.com',
    '',
    $text
);
```

But it's not working, I guess the wildcard isn't properly detecting the pic.twitter.com.

Comment: You want to dynamically remove the `/i4bV2UWkBM` as well (the full URL)?

Comment: I want to remove the full URL, I won't need the /***** either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a regex pattern and use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove the whole URL from the string:

```php
<?php

$replaced = preg_replace(
    '/pic\.twitter\.com\/[a-zA-z0-9]{10}/',
    '',
    <<<TESTS
    Uploading a photo to test the Twitter API endpoint. 
    pic.twitter.com/i4bV2UWkBM … 
    pic.twitter.com/i1bx2U55BM …
    pic.twitter.com/i22x2U55BM …
    TESTS
);

echo $replaced;
```

That code will print the following:

```
Uploading a photo to test the Twitter API endpoint. 
 … 
 …
 …
```

Comment: This works well! Thanks David! By any chance, can you reuse the same preg_replace to pass in two link patterns or would it have to be two separate preg_replace matches?

Comment: You can indeed use one pattern for more URLs. For that, use the regex _OR_ operator, which is `|`. Using the operator you can have multiple options, and when one option matches, the match will be replaced as specified.